# bech32 plus taproot equal bech32m

Tags: bech32-address, bip350-bech32m

need help for one question please !

what can I do with a address bech32 today ?

my old address bech32 must be changed level up to bech32m (taproot) ?

For find, and see my transactions ? On blockchain ?

Comment: There's likely no need for you to turn any Bech32 address into Bech32m.

Answer (score 1):

> what can I do with a address bech32 today ?

Receivers that wish to be paid using a native witness v0 output should construct bech32 addresses. Senders then use these addresses to pay them that way.

> my old address bech32 must be changed level up to bech32m (taproot) ?

You should **never ever** try to convert an address from one type into an other. It is up to the receiver wallet to construct addresses, and decide which addresses they accept.

If you want to start using taproot, use a taproot-compatible wallet, and it will necessarily create bech32m addresses to give out.

Note that not all software and providers support sending to bech32m yet: https://whentaproot.org/

> For find, and see my transactions ? On blockchain ?

In your wallet.

Comment: rhhh...! 
I don't understand !

I have 2-3 old wallet.dat Of 2014 year !

I manipulate them...!

why I can't open my Old wallet (year 2014) ? V.0.9.1, I remerber !

2001 key plaintext = 1 key/address added ?? how I can see the bitcoins on my wallet ?

how I can SEE the bitcoins on my wallet.dat OR see if the bitcoins not here 

but, I think now, I think I have bitcoins ! We know they wrong handling!

I can't see ! 

Help please

Comment: That's an entirely unrelated question. Clearly your wallet from 2014 isn't using taproot or segwit. Please ask on-topic questions, and there are plenty of questions here about recovering old wallets.

Comment: Yes I use bech 32, by base core ! and spares first letter (not added address and key) is 3 and for the key is L and K

Comment: You really need someone to translate for you.

Comment: I don't can chek the all, of the manipulation  + cheminement, please  pieter !  help me, I know for the Dumpwallet + importwallet + backupwallet + rescan..., but I am tired to test cheminement differently.. possible I know the road for, but, I don't realise the commande exact ! today, friend, for exemple, the files .dat have take the wordpad format... and the new backup cannot openning ! and 
 the others yes, (also the format wordpad) ( because the all are) him not .... I am desperate... now you should undersdand, I am applicated

Comment: Can I send you a wallet .dat file? pieter wuille please? To see it "the knot" where it is? and take help for me with what you know and what you see! it's possible ?? no virus, no problem! you can trust me

Comment: No, I don't offer such services. And please stay on-topic; all of this is unrelated to your question here.